# Files installed to C:\ instead of C:\folder\

Tags: nsis

My installer copies Uninstall.exe and /temp/ directory to the installation folder (for me it is C:\MyExample), but MyExample.dll/ico/exe, and success/error.wav are copied directly to C:\ and I can't get this working.

```
 !include "MUI2.nsh"

;General
Function .onInit

  ReadEnvStr $R0 SYSTEMDRIVE

  StrCpy $INSTDIR `$R0\MyExample\`

FunctionEnd
  Name "MyExample"
  OutFile "Setup.exe"
  RequestExecutionLevel admin

;--------------------------------
  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN
  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION "LaunchLink"
  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME ""
  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_NOTCHECKED
  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_TEXT "Create Desktop Shortcut"
  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_FUNCTION finishpageaction
;--------------------------------
;Pages
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
;--------------------------------
;Languages
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections
Section "Dummy Section" SecDummy
  File "MyExample.exe"
  File  "MyExample.ico"
  File  "error.wav"
  File  "success.wav"
  File  "MyExample.dll"
    CreateDirectory $INSTDIR\temp
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\MyExample" "" $INSTDIR

  ;Create uninstaller
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Product\MyExample" \
                 "MyExample" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe$\""
SectionEnd

Section "Uninstall"

# Always delete uninstaller first
delete $INSTDIR\uninstall.exe
  delete $INSTDIR\MyExample.exe
  delete $INSTDIR\MyExample.ico
  delete $INSTDIR\error.wav
  delete $INSTDIR\success.wav
  delete $INSTDIR\MyExample.dll

SectionEnd
;--------------------------------
;Descriptions
  LangString DESC_SecDummy ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Setup"
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SecDummy} $(DESC_SecDummy)
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END

;--------------------------------
;Uninstaller Section

Section "Uninstall"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
  RMDir "$INSTDIR"
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\MyExample"
SectionEnd

Function LaunchLink
  ExecShell "" "$INSTDIR\MyExample.exe"
FunctionEnd

Function finishpageaction
CreateShortcut "$desktop\MyExample.lnk" "$instdir\MyExample.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" \
"MyExample.exe" "$INSTDIR\MyExample.exe"
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Dummy Section` section, you are installing some files without telling the destination directory. I suppose that implicitly meant `$INSTDIR`, but you need to be explicit as a section might or might not be selected (when you have multiple sections), and they must not rely on side effects of previously executed sections (if ever).

Add the destination folder at the beginning of the section, before the `File` statements:

```
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
```